# What is the proper way to animate block resizing after its content changed

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a block with visible text and hidden. After hidden text became visible, main block will change size. What is the proper way to animate this re-sizing? Is it possible to use pure css solution for this?

```css
.wrapper{
  padding: 10px}
.common{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  -moz-transition: max-height 2s;
} 
  p.foo{
    display: none;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="common">
    <button onclick="$('p.foo').toggle()">Click me</button>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod magnam nulla ex aperiam, unde id ea amet tenetur magni harum quibusdam nihil ipsam sed natus excepturi impedit iure sapiente molestias repudiandae a iusto possimus, modi, molestiae saepe ab! Obcaecati odit deserunt alias consectetur perspiciatis, possimus</p>
    <p class="foo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod magnam nulla ex aperiam, unde id ea amet tenetur magni harum quibusdam nihil ipsam sed natus excepturi impedit iure sapiente molestias repudiandae a iusto possimus, modi, molestiae saepe ab! Obcaecati odit deserunt alias consectetur perspiciatis, possimus</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

1. size of block part with hidden text is always the same and can be known
2. size of block part with visible is unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't animate with `display: none;` to `display: block;` but you can animate a height value if you know the new height target value already - you can set the hidden element to 0 with `overflow: hidden;` so nothing of the hidden element will be seen before the click element and if you prefer to make the animate with CSS3 so you can use a new class for the new height value and use the [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) JQuery function.

- i recommend you not to use it as an inline...

HTML & JQuery:

```
<button onclick="$('p.foo').toggleClass('show')">Click me</button>
```

CSS:

```
p.foo
{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;
}

p.foo.show
{
    height: 144px;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/coyxhprp/

Comment: `i recommend you not to use it as an inline` - it was inline just to demonstrate problem. Thanx for your solution.